# SEO wikipedia content and blockquote - duplicate content

Tags: seo, google, html, duplicate-content, wiki

I have a large website that aggregates content both from the websites and Wikipedia. 
Even thought it's someone else content, the way it's combined is unique ad provides a valuable user experience (Google always states it before thinking to SEO).

Every page of the website has at least 10-20 links to a related Wikipedia article (abstract, only first paragraph) + Wikipedia foto. Pretty much like Google does if you search for example "Picasso".

How am I supposed to handle this content? [Here](http://www.pitstopmedia.com/sem/blockquote-cite-q-tags-seo) it is advised to use block quote and cite tags whilst [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302442/does-using-wikipedia-content-harm-a-page-sites-seo-rankings) to link Wikipedia. Should I expose direct Wikipedia link article, should I use the block quote tag, use `rel="nofollow"` or link internal to my site and redirect in this fashion:

```
example.com/wikilinks/?idpage=1

with Disallow: /wikilinks in my robots.txt?
```

All together there will be millions of links pointing to Wikipedia.

Comment: Regarding `nofollow` type links... If you are linking to a genuine trusted source then they should be direct links that pass link juice - you should not use `nofollow` - IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're aggregating from other sources, it doesn't matter if *you* think the way it's combined is unique and a valuable user experience - it's still flying pretty close to [duplicate content](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66359).

I'd be more worried about that than linking out to Wikipedia. There's no way you would be tripping any SEO red flags by linking out to a source site like that.

Citing Wikipedia as the source of the content (`blockquote`s and `cite` tags) is probably your best bet, but i'd consider the actual value of having those pages indexed in the first place when Google would be trying to determine the value of your content compared to the original webpage or Wikipedia.

Comment: mmm, I'm confused! Everyone seems to suggest a different approach! I cannot change the nature of aggregated content, as I developed a search engine and I need to show users the two lines text preview, at the same time the search engine explains concepts by using wiki abstracts. It's a linked data project. So eventually, what's my best bet: block quote, cite and follow? Please, note I have a lot of this links!

Comment: Putting the duplicate content into an iframe and don't let it get crawled might be a solution then?